# Smoke option missing in physics properties

Tags: physics

Im using Blender 2.8.2 and there is no Smoke option on Physics Properties. How to fix it? Here is the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Smoke is a fluid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is under Fluid >> Flow >> Smoke[image]